# No pages of output from the periodic table example

Tags: tikz-pgf

When compiling the example periodic table from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/ I get `No pages of output` from both `latex` and `pdflatex`.

One of the comments under the example also mentioned seeing an empty PDF, but I also checked that no DVI is produced either.

Did anything change in TikZ or PS-Tricks since 2009 that this example does not work anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems to be a problem with preview package, if I remove that it works fine (but I think there are some more elements now:-)

[image]

I just changed the linked code so that it starts

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\advance\paperwidth10cm
\advance\textwidth10cm
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of that package in the example and in general? I looked it up on CTAN but did not quite understand the intended use.

Comment: @aiag the preview package is designed to clip content originally for the auctex system in the emacs editor so you could mark (eg) an equation and it would behind the scenes make a document using preview and just that equation and then "preview" it without showing the full original document.